# how to find parameters used in decision tree algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, classification, scikit-learn, decision-trees

I use a machine learning algorithm, for example decision tree classifier similar to this:

```py
from sklearn import tree
X = [[0, 0], [1, 1]]
Y = [0, 1]
clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()
clf = clf.fit(X, Y)
clf.predict([[2., 2.]])
```

How to find out what parameters are used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just type `clf` after defining it; in your case it gives:

```py
clf
# result:

DecisionTreeClassifier(ccp_alpha=0.0, class_weight=None, criterion='gini',
                       max_depth=None, max_features=None, max_leaf_nodes=None,
                       min_impurity_decrease=0.0, min_impurity_split=None,
                       min_samples_leaf=1, min_samples_split=2,
                       min_weight_fraction_leaf=0.0, presort='deprecated',
                       random_state=None, splitter='best')
```

i.e. all arguments with their default values, since you did not specify anything in the definition `clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier()`.

You can get the parameters of any algorithm in scikit-learn in a similar way.

Tested with scikit-learn v0.22.2

**UPDATE**

As Ben Reiniger correctly points out in the comment below, from scikit-learn v0.23 onwards, we need to set the display configuration first in order for this to work:

```py
sklearn.set_config(print_changed_only=False)
```

Comment: This won't display the default parameters from v0.23, unless you set the configuration parameter `print_changed_only=False`, with `config_context` or `set_config`.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the `get_params` method define for (I believe) all scikit-learn models, as they inherit from [`sklearn.base.BaseEstimator`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.base.BaseEstimator.html). This makes it very easily to create new instances of certain models (although you could also use `sklearn.base.clone`), or save the parameters for later evaluation.

```py
>>> clf.get_params()
{'ccp_alpha': 0.0, 'class_weight': None, 'criterion': 'gini', 'max_depth': None, 'max_features': None, 'max_leaf_nodes': None, 'min_impurity_decrease': 0.0, 'min_impurity_split': None, 'min_samples_leaf': 1, 'min_samples_split': 2, 'min_weight_fraction_leaf': 0.0, 'presort': 'deprecated', 'random_state': None, 'splitter': 'best'}
```